# iPhone app update is submitted with wrong version number

Tags: iphone, app-store, versioning, appstore-approval

Is there a chance of app getting rejected if the iPhone app update is submitted with wrong version number? For instance i had given the version number 1.6 instead of 1.5. The app which exists in app store is of version 1.4.  Will my app update get rejected?

Answer (score 0):

The version number just has to agree with the version number you specify in your Info.plist. Apple does not care about he numeric value, so nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Apple doesn't have a version number naming scheme. As long as your app-version matches the version given in your itunes its not an issue. Also any error related to incorrect versions are reported during submission itself.

So naming scheme is totally dependent on the developer.

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn`t matter.

i have submitted an app with version number 1.3 instead of 1.2 and it was approved.

so don`t worry..